# Take the mean of values in a list if a duplicate is found

Tags: python, arrays, list, for-loop, append

I have 2 lists which are associated with each other. E.g., here, 'John' is associated with '1', 'Bob' is associated with 4, and so on:

```
l1 = ['John', 'Bob', 'Stew', 'John']
l2 = [1, 4, 7, 3]
```

My problem is with the duplicate John. Instead of adding the duplicate John, I want to take the mean of the values associated with the Johns, i.e., 1 and 3, which is (3 + 1)/2 = 2. Therefore, I would like the lists to actually be:

```
l1 = ['John', 'Bob', 'Stew']
l2 = [2, 4, 7]
```

I have experimented with some solutions including for-loops and the "**contains**" function, but can't seem to piece it together. I'm not very experienced with Python, but linked lists sound like they could be used for this.

Thank you

Comment: Isn't Stew associated with7?

Comment: Perhaps what you need is a dict. Have you tried that?

Comment: @schwobaseggl sorry, fixed :)

Comment: @bla yes I did try a dict, but the problem is that since keys can only be unique it doesn't give me a chance to take the mean of the associated values in l2, because it automatically rejects repeated values.

Comment: @MythicCocoa you could try making a list of values associated with `'John'` and then take the mean as you need. Take a look at this answer for adding multiple values to a same key in a dict: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47620204/3044673

Comment: Also you can use `statistics.mean` (https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html#statistics.mean) so that you don't need to actually implement a `mean` function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you should use a **dict**. :)

```
def mean_duplicate(l1, l2):
    ret = {}
    #   Iterating through both lists...
    for name, value in zip(l1, l2):
        if not name in ret:
            #   If the key doesn't exist, create it.
            ret[name] = value
        else:
            #   If it already does exist, update it.
            ret[name] += value

    #   Then for the average you're looking for...
    for key, value in ret.iteritems():
        ret[key] = value / l1.count(key)

    return ret

def median_between_listsElements(l1, l2):
    ret = {}

    for name, value in zip(l1, l2):
        #   Creating key + list if doesn't exist.
        if not name in ret:
            ret[name] = []
        ret[name].append(value)

    for key, value in ret.iteritems():
        ret[key] = np.median(value)

    return ret

l1 = ['John', 'Bob', 'Stew', 'John']
l2 = [1, 4, 7, 3]

print mean_duplicate(l1, l2)
print median_between_listsElements(l1, l2)
# {'Bob': 4, 'John': 2, 'Stew': 7}
# {'Bob': 4.0, 'John': 2.0, 'Stew': 7.0}
```

Comment: AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'iteritems'?

Comment: @MythicCocoa You might be running python 3.x. The python 3 equivalent is `.items()`.

Comment: Good to know :). Elegant solution, worked perfectly, thank you!

Comment: Hi, curious to know if taking the median instead of the mean will make this code more complex

Comment: Why would it be ? It would be a little (little) bit more complex though. What have you tried ?

Comment: I added this at the end, instead of the average (sorry about the bad comment formatting): for key, value in ret.items():
 if l1.count(key) > 1:
  key_values = []
  key_values.append(value)
  ret[key] = np.median(key_values)

Comment: I think perhaps instead of ret[name] += value, the code should be adding the value to a list of previous values associated with the key (as suggested by bla in the comments), but I'm not very sure.

Comment: I've found a solution for implementing the median, its all good :). Thanks once again

Comment: As you wanted to use np.median to make your median, I updated my answer to give you what I would have done.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160723/discussion-between-imcoins-and-mythic-cocoa).

Answer (score 1):

The following might give you an idea. It uses an `OrderedDict` assuming that you want the items in the order of appearance from the original list:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

d = OrderedDict()
for x, y in zip(l1, l2):
    d.setdefault(x, []).get(x).append(y)
# OrderedDict([('John', [1, 3]), ('Bob', [4]), ('Stew', [7])])


names, values = zip(*((k, sum(v)/len(v)) for k, v in d.items()))
# ('John', 'Bob', 'Stew')
# (2.0, 4.0, 7.0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a shorter version using dict,

```
final_dict = {}
l1 = ['John', 'Bob', 'Stew', 'John']
l2 = [1, 4, 7, 3]

for i in range(len(l1)):
    if final_dict.get(l1[i]) == None:
        final_dict[l1[i]] = l2[i]
    else:
        final_dict[l1[i]] = int((final_dict[l1[i]] + l2[i])/2)


print(final_dict)
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
l1 = ['John', 'Bob', 'Stew', 'John']
l2 = [1, 4, 7, 3]
d={}
for i in range(0, len(l1)):
    key = l1[i]
    if d.has_key(key):
         d[key].append(l2[i])
    else:
         d[key] = [l2[i]]
r = []
for values in d.values():
    r.append((key,sum(values)/len(values)))
print r
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope following code helps

```
l1 = ['John', 'Bob', 'Stew', 'John']
l2 = [1, 4, 7, 3]

def remove_repeating_names(names_list, numbers_list):
    new_names_list = []
    new_numbers_list = []
    for first_index, first_name in enumerate(names_list):
        amount_of_occurencies = 1
        number = numbers_list[first_index]
        for second_index, second_name in enumerate(names_list):
            # Check if names match and
            # if this name wasn't read in earlier cycles or is not same element.
            if (second_name == first_name):
                if (first_index < second_index):
                    number += numbers_list[second_index]
                    amount_of_occurencies += 1
            # Break the loop if this name was read earlier.
                elif (first_index > second_index):
                    amount_of_occurencies = -1
                    break
        if amount_of_occurencies is not -1:
            new_names_list.append(first_name)
            new_numbers_list.append(number/amount_of_occurencies)
    return [new_names_list, new_numbers_list]

# Unmodified arrays
print(l1)
print(l2)

l1, l2 = remove_repeating_names(l1, l2)

# If you want numbers list to be integer, not float, uncomment following line:
# l2 = [int(number) for number in l2]

# Modified arrays
print(l1)
print(l2)
```